# Inverse Hessian matrix in Tyler polynomial: intuition.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I just want to confirm if I understand correctly: [here](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2017/cs231n_2017_lecture7.pdf) are slides, see page 45 and few pages ahead. In this case is Hessian matrix(so matrix of second order partial derivatives)...so its inverse are basicly double integrals over region [x, a]X[f(x),f(a), o]??
$$\iint_{[x, a]X[f(x),f(a)]} f(u,v) \,du\,dv$$$$

I just wwant to get intuition right....

UPDATE: $J(\theta)$ is cost function of some paramter matrix $\theta$. Cost being squared difference between forecast of parametric model with parameters $\theta$ and real values. We basicly want to learn best $\theta$(that being the one with lowest cost).

Oh, and if anyone knows what means on page 49 : approximate inverse Hessian with `rank 1 updates over time (O(n^2) each).`

Comment: It is not clear to me what $J$ is (see slide 45) but in general it should be a function $J\colon U\subset \mathbf R^n \to \mathbf R^m$. Then the hessian matrix $H$ is the matrix of all second derivates (as you say). Since $H$ depends on elements in $\mathbf R^n$ I would understand $H^{-1}(x)$ as evaluating $H$ at $x$ ($H(x) \in (\operatorname{Mat}, n\times m)$) and calculating the inverse if it exists. (I did not read all slides!)

Comment: $J(\theta)$ is cost function of some paramter matrix $\theta$. Cost being squared difference between forecast of parametric model with parameters $\theta$ and real values.